How to get timeslots based on start date time and end date time?
I need help in preparing query which will provide me 30 minutes slots based on the start date time and end date time.
For e.g.
In my query in between clause i will provide start date as 2024-11-13 00:00:00 and end date as 2024-11-13 02:00:00.
The query result should return as :
****starttime   endtime****

2018-03-12 00:00:00 2018-03-12 00:30:00
2018-03-12 00:30:00 2018-03-12 01:00:00
2018-03-12 01:00:00 2018-03-12 01:30:00
2018-03-12 01:30:00 2018-03-12 02:00:00


You can try this approach:
WITH RECURSIVE time_slots AS (
    -- Anchor member: Starting point of the time slots (provided start date)
    SELECT 
        CAST('2024-11-13 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS starttime,
        DATE_ADD(CAST('2024-11-13 00:00:00' AS DATETIME), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) AS endtime
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive member: Add 30 minutes to each previous slot
    SELECT 
        DATE_ADD(starttime, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE),
        DATE_ADD(endtime, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
    FROM 
        time_slots
    -- Stop recursion if the endtime exceeds the provided end date
    WHERE 
        endtime < '2024-11-13 02:00:00'
)
-- Select the generated time slots
SELECT starttime, endtime
FROM time_slots
ORDER BY starttime;

ref: https://sqlize.online/sql/mariadb115/ad0e87fbc2b8c8a01615acec7595a0f7/

Please explain how this addresses the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers

endtime in CTE seems to be excess, it can be calculated in outer query.

Quite right - end time out of CTE.

The query works properly till 1001 records.  If i keep end of 2034 year. It not giving all the data

As per check with recursive supports only 1000 records. Hence is there any other way to perform to achieve result ? @danblack

separate ctes for date range and hour, joined.  or just change the max setting.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursion-limits

And MariaDB max_recursive_iterations because they aren't always the same. You can use SET STATEMENT with a CTE like this
